# ACF get data for all posts

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Need to get all ACF data for each post into an array

I tried

```
$fields = get_field_objects();

foreach( $fields as $allData ){
    echo $allData['label']." = ".$allData['value'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

But it only gives me data for current post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Where are you calling this? We need more context in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to loop in every "post" or add other CPT to "post_type"

It's important to use `wp_reset_postdata();` after to return the loop to the current post.

```
<?php
$wpQuery = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => array( 'post' ),
    'post_status'       => array( 'publish' ),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
) );

if( $wpQuery->have_posts() ) :

    while( $wpQuery->have_posts() ) : $wpQuery->the_post();

    $fields = get_field_objects();

    foreach( $fields as $allData ){
        echo $allData['label']." = ".$allData['value'];
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

else :

    // empty

endif;
```